# Remove Duplicates in Excel 2013 keep row with most data in place

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a spreadsheet that looks something like this:

```
Full Name    |      Email          |      Phone Number
---------          -------               -----------
Billy Bob          bob@gmail.com          8019929102
Sally Sue          sue@gmail.com          8013439403
Billy Bob                                 8013432343
                   bob@gmail.com
Sally Sue
Joe So             joe@gmail.com
```

I want to remove duplicates based on email and keep the row that has the most complete data (the most columns filled).  After I do email i'll look for duplicates based on Full Name and then phone number etc..

This is going to be done on almost 500,000 rows of data.

Comment: Would it be viable to export the file into a CSV and parse it with a tool other than Excel?

Comment: I suppose so yes

Comment: which `Phone Number` is correct for Billy Bob?!?

Comment: In this scenario it doesn't matter, either one is just as likely to be correct.  The only thing to worry about is which row has the most data.

Answer (score 0):

Add a helper column that counts the number of fields. Then you can highlight dups.